# Datagridview Class VS 2010 working but not working in VS2015

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, datagridview, c++-cli

Iam using VS2015. Before I used VS2010. For Dynamic DataGridView to ProcessDialogKey , I write the following code works well in VC++ 2010 Windows forms. Now I wish to use that class, but not working.
Receiving the error message 'Failed to load toolbox item MyDataGrid. It will be removed from the toolbox'.

Thanks for the kind helps

My codes:

```
**MyDataGrid.h**

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
#pragma once
public ref class MyDataGrid : DataGridView
{
protected:
 virtual bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData) override;
};


**MyDataGrid.cpp**

#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "MyDataGrid.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
bool MyDataGrid::ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData) {
 Keys key = keyData & (System::Windows::Forms::Keys::KeyCode);
 if (key == System::Windows::Forms::Keys::Enter) {
  DataGridView::OnKeyDown(gcnew KeyEventArgs(keyData));
  return true;
 }
 else {
  return DataGridView::ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
 }
}

**stdafx.h**

#pragma once

**stdafx.cpp**

#include "stdafx.h"
```

Thank for the kind helps

Answer (score 0):

After change to
Common Language Support : CLR.Pure as compile option, my class works fine.